# Coq make failing on Omega

Tags: coq

I'm trying to follow [this](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) but the provided source files are failing `make` with this error

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myhome/Dropbox/org/coq/cpdt'
COQC src/CpdtTactics.v
File "./src/CpdtTactics.v", line 10, characters 0-32:
Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path Omega.
```

in `CpdtTactics.v` there is

```
...
Require Import Eqdep List Omega.
...
```

Where is this `Omega`? One reference mentioned it being deprecated. Another might have mentioned `ZArith` as a substitute. Also, just calling up `InductiveTypes.v` of the cpdt/src files and trying to evaluate line-by-line, I get

```
Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path Cpdt.CpdtTactics.
```

I've got this in my custom-set-variables

```
'(coq-prog-args
   '("-emacs -R /home/myhome/Dropbox/org/coq/cpdt/src Cpdt"))
```

But I'm guessing this is not necessarily my mistake, rather, coq is looking for `CpdtTactics.vo` and it's not there because `make` didn't complete? (In fact, it's not there.)

I'm on coq 8.15 and am using Emacs 28.1/Proof General Version 4.5-git.

BTW, on `https://x80.org/collacoq/` `Require Import Omega.` seems to succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Omega` module and the `omega` tactic have been removed in Coq version 8.14 (after being deprecated in version 8.12).

It seems that the latest CPDT tarball was not updated yet to be compatible with Coq 8.14, so this means that you should compile it with a lower version of Coq, such as version 8.13.

You can install earlier versions of Coq by relying on the [Coq Platform](https://github.com/coq/platform/releases).

If you use the Coq Platform scripts, you can rely on the latest version of the Coq Platform since it provides the option to select an earlier version of Coq. If you'd rather use the binary installers, then you can find installers for Coq 8.13 in a [previous release of the Platform](https://github.com/coq/platform/releases/tag/2021.09.0).

The reason why `Require Import Omega` works on https://x80.org/collacoq is that this website has not been kept up-to-date and is still at Coq version 8.11. If you use https://coq.vercel.app/scratchpad.html instead, you get the latest version of Coq (and thus `Require Import Omega` does not work).

Comment: Thanks. BTW, someone else suggested substituting Lia/lia for Omega/omega. That seemed to work -- but then there were other bugs...