# The reference info was not found in the current environment

Tags: coq

I get `The reference info was not found in the current environment` when I try to do a make on the Adam Chlipala [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) download software cpdt bundle. The file is `LogicProg.v` line 155. There were other problems before this ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298228/coq-make-failing-on-omega)). And lots of errors where I had to change [ ] to { } around stuff. But this seems to be the last bug.

Comment: According to [this page](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/repo), the latest Coq version CPDT seems to accept is 8.11, which is rather old at this point. Which Coq version are you using? If it's a more recent one, perhaps try with 8.11, otherwise you will need to debug lots of things before you can start learning from CPDT. If you really want to port CPDT to a recent version, it might be worth it to look at Coq's [changelog](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding text mentions that `info` is no longer available:

> with the `info` tactical. (This tactical is not available in Coq 8.4 as of this writing, but I hope it reappears soon. The special case `info_auto` tactic is provided as a chatty replacement for auto.)

It was partially replaced by the command [`Info 1`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:cmd.Info):

```
(* Instead of: info auto 6 *)
Info 1 auto 6.
```

Another alternative is to just remove `info` and skip mentions of it.